# Updating files via FTP using Filezilla

Tags: php, ftp, squid, filezilla

Why sometimes when I upload a file from my localhost to production server I must upload it 2 or 3 times to see the new file?

I'm using Filezilla to upload the files and when I do not notice the changes in production server and try to upload again I can see that the file was not changed despite the Filezilla says successfully transferred.

The strange thing is that does not always happen, I thought the problem it was my browser but no, I tried open the page immediately with another browser I got same result.

What is the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know the file is not uploaded properly? Did you SSH to the server and check there? Are you using a HTTP content cache, for example `varnish` or `squid`?

Comment: Because there are differences between size of the files and the php files don't work as should be. And we have squid proxy

Comment: @Shi Do you think squid is guilty?